# How to set a specific div end?

Tags: html, css

im working on a project for myself and im stuck at this point:

```html
<div id="opacity">
  <div id="content">

    <div id="text">
      <h1 id="contentH1">Officiele game-rate website.</h1>
      <br>
      <p id="contentP1">Op deze website kunt u alle top 10 games zien, van veel verschillende genre's. Alle lijsten zijn bedoeld voor de pc. </p>
      <p id="contentP2">Hier onder worden de verschillende genre's aangegeven:</p>

      <ul id="genreIndeling">
        <li>Actie</li>
        <li>Avontuur</li>
        <li>Strategie</li>
        <li>RPG</li>
        <li>Sport</li>
        <li>Race</li>
      </ul>

    </div><!--END TEXT-->

    </div><!--END OPACITY-->

  <div id="messi">
    <img id="messi" src="messi.png" alt="Messi" style="opacity: 1;">
  </div><!--END MESSI-->
  
</div><!--END CONTENT-->
```

Sorry for the Dutch words, but the problem is that my pc, the end div of "content" sees as the end div of "opacity", so my picture got still opacity.

Can anybody help me please?
Thanks,

Joost Keizer

Comment: What's your problem, exactly? The DOM seems correct apart from the fact you didn't close `div#opacity`

Comment: I believe there is no way to closing a specific <div> tag, so why don't you try placing opacity div inside the content div?

Comment: I assume you mean that there is some CSS that is affecting your content. This is happening because all of your content is nested within the `opcacity` `div`. You will either need to take that HTML section out of the `opacity` `div`.

Comment: That's right, placing `div#opacity` inside `div#content` would do the trick, though

Comment: @PedroChiiip *I believe there is no way to closing a specific <div> tag* Of course there is. Tags are closed based on the order they were opened. Proper nesting of tags is the key.

Comment: Another tip: you use the id `messi` twice. An id can only be used once before problems start to occur. Classes can be used multiple times.

Comment: ` </div><!--END OPACITY-->` didnt close the opacity div, it closed the content div

Comment: Ok, I put the div#opacity in the div#content but now the div#content has no opacity anymore.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know that, i just didn't make myself clear. It's just that based on the question, i believe OP is asking if is there any way to do something like "</div#opacity>" to close that div and ignore the nesting order.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing "/div" for opacity

Answer (score 0):

Swap the ids of your first two divs:

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="opacity">
```

This will put your divs in order and keep the image the way you want.

Comment: I've did that but now nothing got opacity anymore.

Comment: Have you looked at the CSS for your two ids? They may be conflicting each other.

Comment: #content {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 600px;
 
 background-color: #55196B;
 
 
 
}


#opacity {
 opacity: 0.6
 
}                    This is my css